# Adding BaseGameUtils to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am trying to add the BaseGameUtils library to my app.

So What I do so far:

I added the GooglePlayServices lib first by downloading the sdk from the sdk manager, and added the dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

then in the manifest

```
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

I create a folder libraries in my app's root folder and added the BaseGameUtils Folder inside that as ;

AndroidStudioProjects\ColorMatch\libraries\BaseGameUtils

And I opened the settings.grandle the added this line `include ':libraries:BaseGameUtils'`

When I tried to extend my class to BaseGameActivity it says cannot resolve symbol.

I can't find any intruction to explain to add BaseGameUtils clearly. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you include a dependency in your app's module for BaseGameUtils?

Comment: Yes I did. compile project('libraries:BaseGameUtils') @ScottBarta

Comment: Does your project sync with Gradle files successfully?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the project to `settings.gradle` you also need to declare the BaseGameUtils project as compile dependency:

```
dependencies {

    // dependencies...

    compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils') // note the leading ':'

}
```